# How to remove link from firebase phone authentication template custom domain?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Saudi Arabia Telecom inbound sms have strict filters on URL - URL can't be share using SMS API - Firebase merge domain name with .com when sending phone authentication code.

After my searching on google for a hour or so, I didn't found any generic solution to this problem. I will be thankful if anyone know solution to the following issue

1. Firebase Phone Template - %APP_NAME% for web - Remove .com only
2. Complete Custom template using arabic with different message.

Comment: This question is somehow region specific - The link you shared is very generic for phone, web. But this is specific for web version only.

Comment: The SMS message Firebase Authentication sends is the same across all regions and platforms, and can't be modified. If the message doesn't work for you, you will have to send your own message through your own SMS provider.